# Seems to be a syntax error in my MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

MySQL is putting off the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `badips` ( `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment, ' at line 2
```

When I run the following PHP:

```
if (file_exists("../login/includes/config.php")) {

    $db_schema = array();

$db_schema[] = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `badips`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `badips` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `host` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `enteredhost` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=26 ;";

require_once('../login/includes/config.php');
require_once('open-db.php');

      echo "<h3>Creating tables...</h3>";
      foreach($db_schema as $sql) {
       mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
      }
      echo "<h3>Done!</h3>";
  }
```

But when I run the same SQL from PHPMyAdmin, it works without any flaws. I can't figure out what the problem is. Anyone know?

Comment: I know you have you answer but just wanted to add that your 'IF NOT EXISTS' next to CREATE TABLE is not needed as your dropping the table before the CREATE.

Comment: @Ash Burlaczenko, thanks, you're right, but I'm paranoid and like to overkill it ridiculously

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mysql_query()` does not support multiple queries. [Quoting the PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> `mysql_query()` sends a unique query **(multiple queries are not supported)** to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified link_identifier.

Comment: Well, I learned something new today. Split it into multiple mysql_query()'s and it worked. Thanks, Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

replace this:

```
$db_schema[] = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `badips`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `badips` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `host` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `enteredhost` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=26 ;";
```

with

```
$query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `badips`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `badips` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `host` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `enteredhost` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=26";

$db_schema = explode(";",$query);
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query() does not support multiple queries., replace with

```
$sql="DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `badips`;";

mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

$sql="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `badips` (`id` int(10) NOT NULL auto_increment, `host` varchar(50) NOT NULL, `ip` varchar(20) NOT NULL, `enteredhost` varchar(50) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=26 ;";

mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```